# Javascript function with request not returning correct value

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm making a node app right now using the `request` node package to connect to APIs. When I make an API request however, the function to determine the validity of a `username` and `password` does not return `true` as expected.

Here's my code so far:

```
const request = require("request")
const API_URL = <the_api_url>

const isValidLogin = (username, password) => {
    let success = false;
    let options = {
        url: API_URL,
        method: 'GET',
        auth: {
            user: username,
            pass: password
        }
    }
    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            success = true;
        }
        else {
            success = false
        }
    })
    console.log(success)
    return success;
}
```

When I pass in an invalid `username` and `password` to `isValidLogin()`, it correctly returns false. I do notice that the `response.statusCode` is `200` which should mean that `success` is `true` however it is not working as expected.

Comment: `request` is asynchronous - so, you're returning `success` before it is populated in the callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `request()` function is asynchronous, which basically means the result of the `request()` function call will returned in the future. In the case of this `request()` method, the result is returned in the future via the callback (ie where you're testing the `statusCode`).

To correctly return the `success` result based on the call to `request()`, you'll need to do one of two things:

1. define `isValidLogin()` as an asynchronous function/return a promise that is resolved in the future:

```
    /* Add asnyc means this function is now asynchronous */
    const isValidLogin = async (username, password) => {
        let success = false;
        let options = {
            url: API_URL,
            method: 'GET',
            auth: {
                user: username,
                pass: password
            }
        }

        /* return the result of the request when the request
        has completed */
        return await (new Promise(resolve, reject) => {
            request(options, (error, response, body) => {

                if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                    resolve(true);
                }
                else {
                    resolve(false);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    /* Requires the surrounding function to be async */
    const success = await isValidLogin('john', 'password');
```

2. or, pass a callback to `isValidLogin` which is called with the `success` result after the `request()` has completed:

```
    /* onComplete is the added callback that is fired when request() completes */
    const isValidLogin = (username, password, onComplete) => {
        let success = false;
        let options = {
            url: API_URL,
            method: 'GET',
            auth: {
                user: username,
                pass: password
            }
        }
        request(options, (error, response, body) => {
            console.log(response.statusCode);
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                onComplete(true);
            }
            else {
                onComplete(false)
            }
        });
    }

    /* Usage example */
    isValidLogin('john', 'password', (success) => {
        console.log(`the request completed in the future 
                     and the result was ${success}`)
    })
```